# Copy pasting from different CSVs to one XLSX file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to succeed the following in VBA:

- Open each file in the folder ( 1 by 1 )
- Since all files are CSVs, I'd like to make them into more columns to gather the data I need.
- I'd like to copy-paste these into one specific excel. These are around 300 rows.
- In that specific Excel I'd like to have them pasted under each other.

What I have already tried:

- The method to find all those files I need.
- Make CSV datas into columns.
- Copy-paste method.
- Find the first empty row down under.

The problem is: I don't have enough knowledge for the macro to do it to all CSVs.

Please see my code below where I got so far:

```
Sub pm_logger()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim bookDest As Workbook
Dim bookFrom As Workbook
Dim lDestLastRow as Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

Workbooks.Open "P:\logs\logstorage.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open "P:\logs\logfile.csv"

Set bookDest = Workbooks("logstorage.xlsx")

Set bookFrom = Workbooks("logfile.csv")

bookFrom.Activate
    Set sh = Worksheets(1)
        With sh
            Set Rng = .Range("A5:A305")
            Set Rng = .Range(Rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp))
                Rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, _
                Comma:=True, _
                Space:=False, _
                Other:=False, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlGeneralFormat), Array(2, xlGeneralFormat), Array(3, xlGeneralFormat)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End With
    
bookFrom.Worksheets(1).Range("A5:K304").Copy

lDestLastRow = bookDest.Cells(bookDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

bookDest.Range("A" & xlDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Workbooks("logstorage.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use the Macro Recorder to do what you need to do manually and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

To get this done, you first need a way to get all your .csv files loaded into your macro. This can be done a few ways, but I suggest a file picker to load them all into a collection:

```
Dim picker As Office.FileDialog
Dim mycsvs As New Collection
Dim file As Variant

Set picker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With picker

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "P:logs\"
    
    If .Show = True Then
    
    For Each file In .SelectedItems
        mycsvs.Add file
    Next file
    
    End If
    
End With
```

Now you have the collection `mycsvs` which holds all the files you selected to be processed. Then all you need after that is to loop over them with the code you have already written:

```
Workbooks.Open "P:\logs\logstorage.xlsx"

For Each file In mycsvs

    Set bookDest = Workbooks("logstorage.xlsx")
    Set bookFrom = Workbooks.open(file)

    'your code here from "Bookfrom.Activate"

    bookFrom.Close SaveChanges:= False

Next file

'Workbooks("logstorage.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
```